# magento custom content in footer area

Tags: magento, footer

is there a way to put a static content in magento footer area, which appears to have different content in each pages.

Comment: could you please more specific about "each page"? those pages whether will be CMS page or not!

Comment: yes it will be cms. can it be done with a footer block? but to what i know a footer block appears the same to every page. Thanks

Comment: it's possible to make different every CMS pages footer area but we need an unique attribute to query. For instance, we can query category attribute then show related footer content. Is it feasible for you?

Answer (score 0):

You required to Footer Links:

The links are available on **Admin menu -> CMS -> Static Block**

Here you choose **Footer Links** and **Add/Modified** your required links.

or modified text of copyright area the code is available at `app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/html/footer.phtml`

Once you try this.